# Is it possible to configure ASP.NET project server properties per user?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is it possible to setup configurations under ASP.NET project properties > Web > Servers for each user that downloads the source code?

[image]

Comment: What are you asking? Sounds like all you need to do is untick the first checkbox.

Comment: Hi @Will, thanks for asking. Sébastien Sevrin got what I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: No.

**Now the explanation**:
These settings are stored in the project file.
Unless you exclude your project file (*.csproj for C# projects) from control versionning, these settings will be shared with all the team.

Before doing so, please note that this is not a solution, because a lot of information is stored in the project files, like files in the project for example.

The best option would be for other users to manually merge project files when there are modifications and commit/check-in the project file only when necessary.